# Extending CGPoint to conform to Hashable

Tags: swift, hash-map, hashcode, swift3

For [Advent of Code Day 1](http://adventofcode.com/2016/day/1), I found myself needing to use a tuple as a key in a dictionary.  Seeing that I can't extend tuples in Swift, I decided to extend `CGPoint` to conform to `Hashable`:

```
extension CGPoint: Hashable {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        return hash()
    }

    func hash() -> Int {
        var hash = 23
        hash = hash &* 31 &+ Int(self.x)
        return hash &* 31 &+ Int(self.y)
    }
}
```

This is based off of an implementation found on Stack Overflow.  Another viable option might be `self.x.hashValue << sizeof(CGFloat) ^ self.y.hashValue` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32988665/2415822)).

This works if the `x` and `y` values of the `CGPoint` are whole numbers, but the `Int` truncation gives a lossy conversion from `CGFloat` to `Int` which could lead to hash collisions.

How can I improve this implementation, and get floating point numbers to play nicely with a hash value that is an `Int`?

Or, would the best approach not even be to extend `CGPoint` at all and to just use a custom Swift container struct or an `NSObject` subclass?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can see no advantage of computing the hash value from `Int(self.x)` and `Int(self.y)`. As you already noticed, truncating the floating point
numbers to integers loses information and therefore causes
hash collisions.

`CGFloat` is (like all Swift number point types) `Hashable`, and its
`hashValue` is just the integer with the same memory representation
(as one can see from the [implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPointTypes.swift.gyb#L767)). So all possible `CGFloat` values have different hash values, which makes `x.hashValue`, `y.hashValue` a much better basis for computing a hash value for `CGPoint` than
`Int(self.x)` and `Int(self.y)`.

It remains the question how to compute the hash value of the point
from the hash values of its coordinates. Of course there can be no
"best hash" which works for all data sets. But in order to get
at least an idea which might be better or worse, I used the
following simple test:

```
var hv = Set<Int>()
var count = 0
for i in -200 ..< 200 {
    for j in -200 ..< 200 {
        count += 1
        let p = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(i)/20, y: CGFloat(j)/20)
        hv.insert(p.hashValue)
    }
}

print(count, hv.count)
```

It computes the hash values of 160,000 points where both
`x` and `y` range from `-20` to `19.9` in steps of `0.1`, and counts
how many different hash values we get.

The referenced hash function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988665/is-there-a-specific-way-to-use-tuples-as-set-elements-in-swift),
translated to Swift 3, is

```
public var hashValue: Int {
    return (self.x.hashValue << MemoryLayout<CGFloat>.size) ^ self.y.hashValue
}
// # of points: 160000 hash values:  79976
```

Your hash function is definitely worse (but we already know why):

```
public var hashValue: Int {
    var hash = 23
    hash = hash &* 31 &+ Int(self.x)
    return hash &* 31 &+ Int(self.y)
}
// # of points: 160000 hash values:  1249
```

Using `hashValue` instead of `Int()` improves it considerably:

```
public var hashValue: Int {
    var hash = 23
    hash = hash &* 31 &+ self.x.hashValue
    return hash &* 31 &+ self.y.hashValue
}
// # of points: 160000 hash values:  68827
```

But this is still not really satisfying.

The Boost library has a [hash_combine()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html)
function for exactly this purpose, and its [implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp)
has one generic variant

```
template <typename SizeT>
inline void hash_combine_impl(SizeT& seed, SizeT value)
{
    seed ^= value + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
}
```

as well as specializations for `uint32_t` and `uint64_t`.
Translated to Swift this would be:

```
func hash_combine(seed: inout UInt, value: UInt) {
    let tmp = value &+ 0x9e3779b9 &+ (seed << 6) &+ (seed >> 2)
    seed ^= tmp
}
```

It is crucial here to use *unsigned* integers, otherwise
the right shift `seed >> 2` would preserve the sign bit.

The Swift `hashValue` is a signed integer, however, therefore
we have to convert accordingly:

```
public var hashValue: Int {
    var seed = UInt(0)
    hash_combine(seed: &seed, value: UInt(bitPattern: x.hashValue))
    hash_combine(seed: &seed, value: UInt(bitPattern: y.hashValue))
    return Int(bitPattern: seed)
}
// # of points: 160000 hash values:  159958
```

As one can see, this hash function has only 42 collisions, and is
far better than the previous ones (for *this* data set). It is also relatively simple to compute, and can easily be adapted
for types with more properties.

If that is not good enough then you can try other "hash combine" methods,
for example the the 32-bit or
64-bit specializations from the Boost library (depending on the
size of `Int` on your platform) and check if that works better.
Another one is
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513911/how-to-create-a-good-hash-combine-with-64-bit-output-inspired-by-boosthash-co),
and there are probably much more.

Finally you asked:

> Or, would the best approach not even be to extend CGPoint at all and to just use a custom Swift container struct or an NSObject subclass?

It depends. If the tuple represents a "point in space" then using (and
extending) `CGPoint` seems fine to me. If the tuple represents something
else (and you just chose `CGPoint` because it happens to have two
properties) then I would prefer to define a custom `struct` which
clearly shows its purpose. A subclass of `NSObject` would be a
reference type and should only be chosen if you need reference
semantics. Otherwise value types are preferable.

---

**Update:** As of **Swift 4.1,** the compiler can synthesize the
conformance to Equatable/Hashable if all of its members are Equatable/Hashable, see [SE-0185 Synthesizing Equatable and Hashable conformance](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/78332d211d00abac286c47609ce1a88a03c6e9bf/proposals/0185-synthesize-equatable-hashable.md).

Example:

```
struct Point : Hashable {
    let x: CGFloat
    let y: CGFloat
}
```

The actual hash function is an implementation detail, but in my test
it worked excellently: The above test code produced no collisions at all
for the 160,000 points.

Comment: Thanks Martin!  The references to FloatingPointTypes.swift and the boost `hash_combine()` function are especially helpful!  My hash worked for a very small data set, but this will surely help with larger sets.

Comment: Semi-related: I've been going back and forth with another user about CGPoint equality.  Care to chime in?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/45449576/2415822

Comment: @JAL: Things became much simpler in Swift 4.1 – see update!

Comment: It won't let me update the answer since it's only a 2 character difference, but I believe every time you write "16,000", you meant to write "160,000". Also for anyone looking for the latest way to conform to Hashable without using a 3rd party library, I believe [this is the recommended way](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/252541/233621).

Comment: @Senseful: Yes, you are right, `hash(into:)` is how it is done in Swift 5. – Unfortunately, `CGPoint` is not already Hashable, nor can the hash function be auto-synthesized. That's why I chose a custom `Point` type in my last example.

Answer (score 1):

Martin's answer is excellent. The one thing missing is how to extend CGPoint to conform to Hashable using the [native hasher functions](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-conform-to-the-hashable-protocol):

```
extension CGPoint: Hashable {
  public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(x)
    hasher.combine(y)
  }
}
```

After running his tests, it too did not produce any collisions:

```
160000 160000
```

The nice thing about making `CGPoint` conform to Hashable is then all your types that use CGPoint can benefit from automatic hashable conformance.